# How to concatenate SQL distinct query results into a string?

Tags: mysql

How to get the distinct values from a column and concatenate them into one string?  Thanks.

For example, I have a column like

```
fruit_name
------
apple
apple
apple
banana
orange
orange
.
.
.
```

I want to create a result like `apple, banana, orange...`

Here is the query I have tried but it will only give a result of `apple, apple, apple, banana...`

```
SELECT LISTAGG(fruit_name,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fruit_name) "fruit_List" FROM FRUIT_TABLE;
```

I have no idea how to make the result distinct.

Comment: `LISTAGG` is not available in MySQL. Are you sure you want a solution for MySQL?

Comment: @Natsuki_Kato Are you really using MySQL, or are you using SQL Server of possibly Oracle (in which the answer will be a lot longer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT()` function to solve your problem:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.fn)
FROM
(
    SELECT fruit_name fn
    FROM FRUIT_TABLE
    GROUP BY fruit_name
) t
```

The default separator in `GROUP_CONCAT` is a comma, which is what you specified in your original problem.

**Update:**

I give credit for this solution to @cars10 who pointed out that everyone initially got this wrong.

Comment: My answer was posted first.  Just thought I'd say that :-)

Comment: My initial solution was more or less identical to yours but, unfortunately, both are wrong, see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfbf4/1

Answer (score 1):

Try This Query,

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fruit_name) FROM FRUIT_TABLE ORDER BY fruit_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query using `GROUP_CONCAT` since `LISTAGG` is not available in mysql:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fruit_name ORDER BY fruit_name ASC SEPARATOR ',') as fruit_List
FROM FRUIT_TABLE
```

`GROUP_CONCAT` has `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` attributes included

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** (my first version was plainly wrong!)

```
select group_concat(fn) fruit_list
from (select fruit_name fn 
         from fruit_table 
         group by fruit_name) fruits
```

Now it works, see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfbf4/2 but Nikhil Batra's solution is clearly a better choice!